# Hung application in shell

Tags: linux, shell, kill

Sometimes when an application hangs in bash session (e.g. network lags in `telnet`, `ssh`, whatever) I can't kill it with ^C, stop it with ^D and even send it to background with ^Z.

Is there a way to kill it without opening another shell with `kill`? I guess there's a syscall to interrupt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using SSH, try the two ketstroke combination: ~ ^z  (tilde, and then control-z).  This will escape out of the SSH session.  The same can be done with telnet by pressing ^]  (ctrl and then ]).

Now you can start a new session and kill the offending process or the entire session.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yep, looks like a solution, thank you :) I'll test it ASAP. But is there a more universal solution? Maybe, some 'emergency' hotkey can be mapped in bash that kills the current task?

Comment: In you ran inside of screen, you could open a new window and then kill the process.

Comment: @o_O Tync: ^C, ^D and ^Z *are* the emergency hotkeys.

Answer (score 2):

You can send the process a `SIGQUIT` with a Ctrl-\ which sometimes works if the process has a signal handler for `SIGTERM` (Ctrl-c) or `SIGSTOP` (Ctrl-z).

If your process is blocking on I/O syscalls (ps shows it in state D,) it's in an uninterruptable sleep and you're going to have to wait until the resource it's waiting for starts responding.